# Sheets: Array result not expanded

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to use an array formula to calculate the 'days since last contact' in column U of my sheet. I started with:

```
=DATEDIF(V60, Today(), "D")
```

Which worked well and entered the number 1 in column U (I'm writing this on 12/7). Next I tried to turn this into an arrayformula which I've placed above the frozen header row in column U (#REF in screenshot). I'm trying:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(V2:V),"",DATEIF(V2, Today(), "D")))
```

The result that I'm looking for is in the following screenshot (assume today is 12/9):

[image]

That is, whenever a timestamp appears in column V, the array formula in the U cell next to it will keep a running tally of the number of days between the current day and the timestamp in U.

However the resulting #REF error reads:

Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in U3 . How can I get this working?

edit:

unfortunately that formula leads to the same "array not expanded" error:

[image]

edit2: following your directions I deleted the contents of u3 and placed the formula in u2:

[image]

I'm using an app script function on a timer to update PENDING to a timestamp using the apps script Date() function:

```
var u = updateRow(pendingRow,'3','last_contacted',new Date() )
```

This may account for differences in appearances after I cleared formatting from row V. However I looked at these and I can verify that they are date time objects.

[image]

Comment: its a row header - I can't do that.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: You wanted a picture to make it clearer, so I provided that. There is no actual formula  present in U9 or U10, although as I said above "=DATEDIF(V6, Today(), "D")" works for U6. I'm looking for a way to apply this formula to a full column. U1-3 are frozen header rows, with the actual header in U3. U4 is the first data row , so I assumed that I'd try to stay out of that row with an array formula.

Comment: Please see edit above

Comment: Please see edit2

Comment: please see edit

Comment: Seems isdate()  doesn't support arrays. Added a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array literals](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to join strings and formula.

U2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"";"days since";IFERROR(IF(V4:V*1<>0,DATEDIF(V4:V,TODAY(),"D"),))})
```

Comment: It appears to be working now. One of the problems was I was putting it into a frozen row. I had to unfreeze the header rows,  put in the formula and refreeze.